# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Pets's [first moderator election](https://pets.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: Harry V.]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5885160706801664/0).

Answer (score 7):

### Congratulations, Harry V!

Really glad that you'll be joining the team :)

A huge thanks to everyone who nominated themselves to become a moderator - I had a really hard time voting because all of you would have made great additions as moderators!

Comment: Congratulations! Pets is in safe hands!

Answer (score 4):

***Congratulations Harry V!***

Really happy for you - and really pleased to see a vet join the mod team!